# Inner join error

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008, sql-server-2005

[image]

How to join this 2 tables? Common column is `ref#no`.

But I get an error

> Column 'Ink Delivery.DELDATE' is invalid in the select list because
>   it is not contained in either an aggregate function or the GROUP BY
>   clause

```
SELECT 
    a.REF#NO, a.DELDATE, a.REQUST_By, a.PROJ_CODE, 
    b.PR_CODE, b.INK_CODE, b.QTY, b.PRICE 
from [Ink Delivery detals] b
inner join [Ink Delivery] a ON a.REF#NO = b.REF#NO
GROUP by a.REF#NO
```

Comment: Just don't add the `GROUP BY` - you don't need it, you're not using any aggregate functions (like `SUM` or `COUNT`)

Comment: yuo have to omit the group by clause, you may use the group by clause when you are working with aggregate functions like count()

Comment: -1 for not selecting an answer

Answer (score 3):

This is not an inner join problem. Look at the error you getting. You are attempting to do a Group By, but you have columns in your Select statement that are not contained in the Group By clause. When doing a Group By, your Select statement can only contain columns referenced in the Group By clause or aggregate columns (e.g., Sum, Average).

You might want to brush on how to use [Group By](http://www.sqlteam.com/article/how-to-use-group-by-in-sql-server) in SQL Server.

Answer (score 3):

```
SELECT 
    a.REF#NO, a.DELDATE, a.REQUST_By, a.PROJ_CODE, 
    b.PR_CODE, b.INK_CODE, b.QTY, b.PRICE 
from [Ink Delivery detals] b
inner join [Ink Delivery] a ON a.REF#NO = b.REF#NO
ORDER BY a.REF#NO
```

is the correct way.